# Check if NTP Client Daemon is Working properly Using NTPDC

Tags: server, client, ntp

How can i check if a NTP client is working properly **solely by using ntpdc** command?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Type **`ntpdc -c peers`** into terminal. Or **`ntpdc -p`** should do it as well.

Both commands effectively print out a list of the peers known to the server as well as a summary of their state.

Observe output and confirm whether or not the daemon is working properly.